# Program works on dev machine, but won't start on test machine

Tags: c#, startup

I've been writing this program for a while now, and I'm finally ready to start testing it.  It works 100% on my dev machine, but I wanted to try it on a machine it's never run on.  So, I get my program over to a test computer.  When I double-click the exe, nothing happened.  I opened up task manager, and tried again.  I saw the process start, but after about 5 seconds, it disappeared.  No errors, no exceptions, no nothing.  How would I go about trying to figure out what is going wrong?  I'm still fairly new, and I've never had this happen.  Thanks for any and all help!

*EDIT*

Sorry for not mentioning before.  This is a winforms application.

*EDIT 2*

So, turned out what was going on is that I was trying to a dll meant for 64-bit OS into a 32-bit OS.  In Windows XP, this threw a BadImageFormatException.  However, in Windows 7, as I stated, it threw no exception at all.

Comment: Paragraphs could be nice! + Is it a console program?

Comment: What's the debugger show you? You should use a debugger to launch your program on the test machine, and see what is happening.

Comment: @StarPilot:  Being still the learner, what debugger can I use to launch the program?  Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately the primary debugging environment you'd want for this situation is a copy of VS.

Comment: I'm having the same sort of issue myself at the moment.  I can't install a copy of visual studio onto my test environment because it has to stay as "clean" as possible.  So I created a simple WriteToLog file method and I have the application write to a text file at key stages.  It's gone a long way to try and solve what the actual issue is.  You can put as much information into your log as you want.  I have it writing the name of the method as well as at key points.  I also have it writing out any exceptions that it comes across.  I found this the best way of debugging a dll I'm trying to test

Comment: You can install the windows debugger, windbg.exe FOR FREE on your test machine, if it isn't already present. You will find it is part of the microsoft debugginger SKD at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx 
You can find debugging information/documentation at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=VS.85).aspx 
A small tutorial can be found at: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6084/Windows-Debuggers-Part-1-A-WinDbg-Tutorial
You can search MSDN or your favorite search engine for more help in using windbg.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pickle, no doubt about it. I've had to debug this type of thing before.

The first bit of useful information is that no exception is being thrown out. This tells me that somewhere in your actual code is the key to solving the problem. You are either trapping an exception and closing silently, or your code is hitting what it considers to be a "normal" exit condition and is closing in what it would consider the normal way.

To figure out where and why it's exiting, I would add debug logging at key points in your application, and attach a listener to the Debug/Trace listener collection that writes out to a file. "Key points" are places where the application is supposed to exit (or the main form of the window is supposed to close), and within any "catch" block or error event handler. Run this new version on the test computer and see what it gives you. That should tell you the basic flow of the program behind the scenes, and through what mechanism it's shutting down.

Comment: I added some logging to it, and found that I was trying to load a 64-bit dll in a 32-bit OS.  So silly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a console application, it is possible that it runs and then closes itself.
Trying opening a command prompt, and then executing the application from there.
If your program has output, then you would see it in that command window.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the application event log?

Do you have the necessary version(s) of .Net installed?

Perhaps you should put more exception handling with calls to MessageBox.Show("I failed **here**") through out your application.